# Controlling FusionCharts legend overflow

Tags: javascript, xml, fusioncharts

I have an issue with precise control of FusionCharts legend and would like someone to help.

What I want to do is either print all 3 categories in one line or one column - but even though this is supposedly configurable, the FusionCharts renderer resists me. The best I could get was 2 columns without overflowing letters... :)

This is an example of the graph:

[image: Example graph]

The chart type is "ScrollColumn2D" (width: 230, height: 180) and these are the options being fed to it:

```
<chart showValues='1' formatNumberScale='0' useRoundEdges='1' showBorder='0'
    bgColor='FFFFFF' showTooltip='0' flatscrollbars='1' scrollshowbuttons='0'
    scrollcolor='#cccccc' showlegend='1' legendNumColumns='3' legendbgcolor='#ffffff'
    legendborderalpha='0' legendshadow='0' legenditemfontsize='8' 
    legenditemfontcolor='#666666'> 

    <categories> 
        <category label='...' />
        ...
    </categories> 

    <dataset seriesName='Successful' color='33CC00'> 
        <set label='Successful' value='...' link='...' color='33CC00' />
        ...
    </dataset> 

    <dataset seriesName='Suspect' color='e5e500'> 
        <set label='Suspect' value='...' link='...' color='E5E500' />
        ...
    </dataset> 

    <dataset seriesName='Failed' color='e50000'> 
        <set label='Failed' value='...' link='...' color='E50000' />
        ...
    </dataset> 

</chart>
```

As you can notice - the number of columns is defined to be 3, but it doesn't seem to bother the renderer too much. -_-

Important caveat:

The graph div size must stay unchanged (the image is exactly the size of it). Otherwise, obviously, the issue would be trivial.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: If you want all of them in 1 column you can set the `legendNumColumns` to one, But all of them in one line, seems not configurable from the API.

Comment: I've tried that before, I remember now - it results in one scrolling column (which is unsuitable); but thanks for the suggestion. :)
Edit: seeing that you work there, I guess that's a valid answer from FusionCharts... Any way to submit a feature request? :D

Comment: A related possibility: is it possible to center the legend's content?

Comment: You can definitely log a request with our [support](http://support.fusioncharts.com). The legend is already centered in respect to canvas. Can you please elaborate a bit more on this, if that is not what you meant.

Comment: Thanks! I meant the words to be centered inside the legend itself (in particular, the "failed" word to be in the center, and not under "successful").

Comment: Its my pleasure! I guess, thats also not possible. If your text (series name) goes too long the legend item for 'failure' will shift towards right. But then also it won't be central aligned.